# How to read from file after some 'mark'?

Tags: python

For example, if I have some text / log file with very simple structure, where here is a few different parts of it, with different structure, and splitted by some mark line, e.g.:

```
0x23499 0x234234 0x234234
...
0x34534 0x353454 0x345464
$$$NEW_SECTION$$$
4345-34534-345-345345-3453
3453-34534-346-766788-3534
...
```

So, how I can read file by these parts? E.g. read file in one variable before that `$$$NEW_SECTION$$$` mark, and after it (without using regexps, etc). Are here any simple solutions for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the solution without reading the whole file into memory:

```
 data1 = []
 pos = 0
 with open('data.txt', 'r') as f:
     line = f.readline()
     while line and not line.startswith('$$$'):
         data1.append(line)
         line = f.readline()

     pos = f.tell()

 data2 = []
 with open('data.txt', 'r') as f:
     f.seek(pos)
     for line in f:
         data2.append(line)

 print data1
 print data2
```

The first iteration can't be made with `for line in f` not to spoil the accurate position in the file.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is [str.split](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split)

```
>>> s = filecontents.split("$$$NEW_SECTION$$$")
>>> s[0]
'0x23499 0x234234 0x234234\n\n0x34534 0x353454 0x345464\n'
>>> s[1]
'\n4345-34534-345-345345-3453\n3453-34534-346-766788-3534'
```

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1:**

If file is not very-big then:

```
with open('your_log.txt') as f:
  parts = f.read().split('$$$NEW_SECTION$$$')
  if len(parts) > 0:
    part1 = parts[0]
    ...
```

**Solution 2:**

```
def FileParser(filepath):
  with open(filepath) as f:
    part = ''
    while(line = f.readline()):
      part += line
      if (line != '$$$NEW_SECTION$$$'):
        returnpart = part
        part = ''
        yield returnpart


for segment in FileParser('your_log.txt'):
    print segment
```

Note: it is untested code so please validate before using it

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

```
def sec(file_, sentinel):
    with open(file_) as f:
        section = []
        for i in iter(f.readline, ''):
            if i.rstrip() == sentinel:
                yield section
                section = []
            else:
                section.append(i)
        yield section
```

and use:

```
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> pprint(list(sec('file.txt')))
[['0x23499 0x234234 0x234234\n', '0x34534 0x353454 0x345464\n'],
 ['4345-34534-345-345345-3453\n',
  '3453-34534-346-766788-3534\n',
  '3453-34534-346-746788-3534\n']]
>>>
```

sections to variables or best sections to dict:

```
>>> sections = {}
>>> for n, section in enumerate(sec('file.txt')):
...     sections[n] = section
>>>
```